# I can’t connect to any secured host which is protected with Lets Encrypt SSL on Windows 8.1

Tags: security, ssl, letsencrypt

I have problems with `Windows 8.1` where I can’t connect to any host which is protected with Lets Encrypt.

1. IE 11 not working and display `this page cannot be displayed`.
2. Executing code from CURL or C# also fails with SSL/TLS handshake
   error.

I have tried to test using OpenSSL

```
s_client -host 7bdcc6a8-e7c1-49b2-9119-8ff819e17b6e.blrrvkdw0thh68l98t20.databases.appdomain.cloud -port 443 -debug -security_debug
```

and got an error in results

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

The result from OpenSSL

```
CONNECTED(00000110)
write to 0xf5e69f0ea0 [0xf5e6a14f20] (385 bytes => 385 (0x181))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 7c 01 00 01-78 03 03 c3 6a 1d 7b 63   ....|...x...j.{c
0010 - 65 57 12 5e 11 31 d5 da-ff 9c e6 7d e7 0f cf c5   eW.^.1.....}....
//SKIP
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = icd-prod-us-east-db-a0qmx.us-east.containers.appdomain.cloud
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = icd-prod-us-east-db-a0qmx.us-east.containers.appdomain.cloud

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3264 bytes and written 465 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
read from 0xf5e69f0ea0 [0xf5e6a0bd03] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 17 03 03 01 5a                                    ....Z
read from 0xf5e69f0ea0 [0xf5e6a0bd08] (346 bytes => 346 (0x15A))
0000 - 7f 6d 39 89 2a 3c 0b 83-43 dd 34 70 16 8a e0 e9   .m9.*<..C.4p....
0010 - 5d ab 31 2f 0b c6 c3 22-54 a7 22 b5 64 2a 96 75   ].1/..."T.".d*.u
0020 - c2 ce fa d7 a3 55 d0 9f-bd ad bb 06 b6 d5 b7 6e   .....U.........n
0030 - 78 02 0b fc fa 5b ea f9-be 44 cd f0 be 3f 02 09   x....[...D...?..
0040 - 83 74 75 73 b4 96 0e fb-72 dd fc 75 f9 cf e6 06   .tus....r..u....
0050 - 15 0a 20 86 a1 11 fd ec-15 9b 59 1e f0 5a 83 74   .. .......Y..Z.t
0060 - dd 5c 69 09 c4 f6 cc e7-56 f2 77 48 8b f0 3e 12   .\i.....V.wH..>.
0070 - 6f d2 85 b8 a6 8b af a8-82 fd 42 0c 8a 4f 2a 98   o.........B..O*.
0080 - 44 8f c4 b1 bb 15 22 ad-68 94 4a de 29 9d 7f 08   D.....".h.J.)...
0090 - 7a 16 f1 f7 24 e2 a8 05-73 bd f5 48 d3 74 12 95   z...$...s..H.t..
00a0 - f3 e4 7b 37 6b 41 03 6c-d5 10 e2 76 41 c0 5b 24   ..{7kA.l...vA.[$
00b0 - 73 55 ad 13 df 86 95 ff-c3 ed 83 9d 46 4e 1b 15   sU..........FN..
00c0 - ea 94 05 ad 00 f3 de fd-d5 5b aa a6 55 a5 1b 5d   .........[..U..]
00d0 - f7 b6 29 b7 96 4d d9 b1-59 4e 97 2e a2 a7 9e 77   ..)..M..YN.....w
00e0 - 24 6d 75 09 c6 9b 22 38-9d b9 86 3b b1 30 23 f9   $mu..."8...;.0#.
00f0 - 6d 7b 48 6e c6 54 1a 12-38 ba 1d 8b cd 18 ea 15   m{Hn.T..8.......
0100 - 03 92 69 06 92 cd 68 33-ef cb 51 1f 11 f3 4b 49   ..i...h3..Q...KI
0110 - df e9 b0 69 47 8a f8 ff-50 31 c8 9b c7 e1 50 b3   ...iG...P1....P.
0120 - 22 8a b8 3c 6b 9d 09 17-87 6b e3 1a ea 62 6a 87   "..<k....k...bj.
0130 - 2d 75 88 fb 6b 73 9c 82-76 87 b3 e2 ef 03 5c b8   -u..ks..v.....\.
0140 - 2a 3e e4 33 55 03 53 40-d0 dc 39 1b 43 52 52 ca   *>.3U.S@..9.CRR.
0150 - ae bb 51 44 17 f7 c5 57-98 c0                     ..QD...W..
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: F2D113A783DED6C73955EBC9DBE23290DE69ED6AF528EA4563F59BAE84390427
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: E04A19DAB3AD0E09224CBF1DDC04385C732A5E3F2B8056269F29D7E916112F8FAFD3C668005483F0666C71182F4AE991
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 4c 39 8c a2 6f 4f b7 fb-22 4d 5e 75 99 04 2c c7   L9..oO.."M^u..,.
    0010 - b5 9a 5d 04 dc e5 aa a5-83 60 08 41 12 2c cd 69   ..]......`.A.,.i
    0020 - 82 c7 00 6b 5d 6f 80 2c-38 70 38 ae 48 d9 38 ad   ...k]o.,8p8.H.8.
    0030 - 39 d9 0e 0d b1 ca 76 1e-ef 0b 60 9b 5b 84 e4 ad   9.....v...`.[...
    0040 - 38 05 85 8a cc 17 91 40-66 10 b5 5e d7 14 92 02   8......@f..^....
    0050 - 5b 2e 5c b0 e4 0e d2 86-af c2 f1 5d 9a 85 1e a9   [.\........]....
    0060 - fd 57 90 84 7f 3a f7 94-fa bf e9 45 aa 8b b8 7c   .W...:.....E...|
    0070 - 32 d9 2f 97 d9 87 52 85-ac 39 41 ae 7e 39 0d 17   2./...R..9A.~9..
    0080 - ca 16 47 ba 88 6e 7a 12-71 03 14 62 0d 1a b8 76   ..G..nz.q..b...v
    0090 - 16 e8 45 65 0e f3 5e 0b-99 32 cd ba 12 c0 e1 ea   ..Ee..^..2......
    00a0 - 7a 1e 79 b9 40 27 2f 2b-86 29 60 af 25 4a 40 2f   z.y.@'/+.)`.%J@/
    00b0 - 91 4e d7 2a a6 26 37 54-35 0b a2 4c da fb 4c bc   .N.*.&7T5..L..L.
    00c0 - 67 ef 3a c3 e9 b6 a5 cb-85 fd 51 a6 e5 28 d2 7e   g.:.......Q..(.~
    00d0 - b8 fc bb 08 01 d9 ab 9a-b8 32 f2 00 ac ba d0 f3   .........2......
    00e0 - e0 95 a8 a1 32 61 4e b5-35 39 52 67 8d 76 6d f0   ....2aN.59Rg.vm.
    00f0 - 79 d2 60 c9 17 02 59 28-24 bb c0 16 08 18 d1 a2   y.`...Y($.......
    0100 - 97 20 ee f9 f5 77 93 9b-70 2f aa bb e8 c1 14 95   . ...w..p/......
    0110 - d4 c3 36 e1 43 62 91 96-0e f5 2d 8f 89 7e aa b3   ..6.Cb....-..~..
    0120 - a4 c5 0f 64 da 7f 58 e3-29 4c ba f1 5f 4b 27 46   ...d..X.)L.._K'F

    Start Time: 1595413991
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
read from 0xf5e69f0ea0 [0xf5e6a0bd03] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 17 03 03 01 5a                                    ....Z
read from 0xf5e69f0ea0 [0xf5e6a0bd08] (346 bytes => 346 (0x15A))
0000 - 5e 12 01 e3 1f ef fd 74-9b 64 04 a1 c7 0d af b9   ^......t.d......
0010 - 42 60 7c 9c f6 ac b6 86-99 53 f3 0b 1e 11 99 87   B`|......S......
0020 - 6e e7 02 03 59 a9 fe 60-1b e3 9f ea 57 1f 9f ad   n...Y..`....W...
0030 - 15 72 e0 fe 49 cb b5 03-ac 5e 80 86 06 90 28 98   .r..I....^....(.
0040 - 24 21 1b 48 b6 7e 56 bf-2c 4a be d7 60 41 9c 63   $!.H.~V.,J..`A.c
0050 - f4 23 ea b8 da 2e 3e 81-f8 dc 70 c8 5a 17 a2 21   .#....>...p.Z..!
0060 - 30 4d 34 2b 97 82 2e 5a-a3 4d 72 d2 40 27 ca a8   0M4+...Z.Mr.@'..
0070 - 64 4e 33 c9 9c 65 6b 14-ce 12 93 5b f0 77 1e 9a   dN3..ek....[.w..
0080 - 3d 09 98 a1 a3 fa d6 21-7b 9a ce e0 36 96 35 97   =......!{...6.5.
0090 - bb 75 cc c3 f4 6d 0c 38-02 1c 06 ce 3d 2d 2f 54   .u...m.8....=-/T
00a0 - bc 1a 13 f9 01 47 74 a0-54 49 98 09 5d f2 bb 1e   .....Gt.TI..]...
00b0 - ff 2c be 62 9c f3 10 da-6e 38 65 f2 98 7e 18 ac   .,.b....n8e..~..
00c0 - 64 ce 66 5c 43 f0 23 32-52 ec 7b 08 7e c5 83 19   d.f\C.#2R.{.~...
00d0 - 97 22 ae 6f c3 4d 9e cf-a4 70 46 4b f3 08 39 50   .".o.M...pFK..9P
00e0 - 0c ba d4 bd 57 7c b9 81-ac b6 a6 a6 ac d9 9b 85   ....W|..........
00f0 - 4e e7 97 b3 23 63 aa 87-a1 f5 08 37 00 ce 6a 07   N...#c.....7..j.
0100 - 1d eb cb 44 f1 77 eb 70-68 d9 ed 35 11 a5 ca e3   ...D.w.ph..5....
0110 - 63 de 47 ee 66 b2 59 03-b2 d8 4d b0 90 12 14 26   c.G.f.Y...M....&
0120 - d2 76 64 65 72 6a 72 11-5f fd 13 ba 8f 18 e5 d7   .vderjr._.......
0130 - 5e 32 d4 4f 50 ab e2 36-ab e8 d6 04 43 65 2a 88   ^2.OP..6....Ce*.
0140 - e7 91 81 39 f7 bd 27 b4-c5 c7 4a fc a9 7a 82 2e   ...9..'...J..z..
0150 - bd bd af 8d b2 1a 58 8a-80 e5                     ......X...
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: E30D3E8C3D51CDD637910201E78CC5FA5DDFCAA75DB475F11B32FFA9FA94E6DA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 9D0A84FA48606A445C1D00A9AB9C94A10C69FE083F354096ABE3F5D1D0179CCD4B66415D4576DE85D95995A61F30B3F0
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 4c 39 8c a2 6f 4f b7 fb-22 4d 5e 75 99 04 2c c7   L9..oO.."M^u..,.
    0010 - 24 46 ff 7a 2a 6f 77 6b-7f 00 02 75 0a e5 1b 2a   $F.z*owk...u...*
    0020 - 89 7e 98 61 a2 d2 22 54-e1 cf 7b 84 fa 8d 43 6c   .~.a.."T..{...Cl
    0030 - 0a 44 21 bb de f6 b0 c8-de ab 60 6c e7 5e 54 10   .D!.......`l.^T.
    0040 - b5 41 71 53 73 19 ad dc-dc 22 e0 15 1f ab 2f 3c   .AqSs...."..../<
    0050 - f2 5d dc 18 a0 5e 0e 71-26 47 be 08 1f 6b 90 33   .]...^.q&G...k.3
    0060 - de 95 da f3 5b 4b 63 e6-33 d4 0b 10 4b 3c f1 c1   ....[Kc.3...K<..
    0070 - f2 14 c8 21 42 d7 fc a8-86 31 56 b8 3b 9e d7 37   ...!B....1V.;..7
    0080 - d5 9c c2 3a c7 89 52 36-75 80 4f 0c eb 7f 97 3e   ...:..R6u.O....>
    0090 - ec 31 3e 74 05 56 fa 12-08 ac 19 73 1e 6a 3b 81   .1>t.V.....s.j;.
    00a0 - 1d 2d 53 96 94 fc a6 08-0c 02 c1 6a d6 ec ed 93   .-S........j....
    00b0 - b3 62 9c 66 41 9a fa 3c-67 53 b0 0e 6e 23 59 66   .b.fA..<gS..n#Yf
    00c0 - 13 73 a4 d2 92 c9 01 6d-ba af 43 d1 29 63 00 7b   .s.....m..C.)c.{
    00d0 - e5 00 0f 3f 72 07 08 7e-b0 6b f7 d4 d8 b8 30 22   ...?r..~.k....0"
    00e0 - e6 03 f1 d9 68 6c c6 67-d0 b3 84 0c fd de 9d 61   ....hl.g.......a
    00f0 - ae ee a1 96 ea 61 66 5f-7c 92 a6 41 f4 4b f4 d7   .....af_|..A.K..
    0100 - 83 2a a4 b9 3c 57 98 0c-cb 52 bb c0 f5 fd 6a c4   .*..<W...R....j.
    0110 - 8b bf d0 e2 59 ab 79 59-32 49 89 3d de a6 81 b4   ....Y.yY2I.=....
    0120 - a5 85 fa d3 4b bb 7f 31-f0 48 19 60 35 4f c4 3a   ....K..1.H.`5O.:

    Start Time: 1595413991
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
```

Comment: Try to clear the cache of the browser

Answer (score -1):

it seems an issue related specifically to your workstation not global windows 8.1

have a look at https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/101044 it explains full details which doesn't make sense to copy them all here :)

good luck

Comment: Sorry but I do not find any real explanation of how to solve the problems in that post.

Comment: Down voted as link only answers are frowned upon, and @thomas is right - this link is meaningless.

Comment: you mentioned that its working from other PCs except this windows 8.1 PC, so its related to your PC not global thing. the link explains how to check the host remotely using SSL isntaller checkers, if its working then its confirmed the issue at your PC not the server